# Group heading does not repeat

Tags: grouping, rdlc, repeat

I want the Group Headings to Repeat on subsequent pages.

Below `RDLC` Images show all of my settings and 2 pages from the report:-

[image]

Comment: I was able to solve this.  I think I was creating the form incorrectly. Apparently the correct way to add groups to the form is from the 'bottom-up'.  I was adding groups from the "top-down" and that was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to create a form with groups, you build the form from the 'bottom-up'.  Starting with the outermost group and working inward.
1. Insert the highest-level parent group.
2. Delete the column that is created - column-only, not group.
3. Create row - 'Outside Group - Above'
4. Repeat until you have all of your groups. [Image of RDLC form showing nesting of groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qqwsf.jpg)